# How to print output of bash array on single line

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, awk, grep

My code is

```
arr=($(awk '/"*"/' output.txt))
```

And output.txt says has following content -

```
user  
{  
'xx123':  
comment
=>  
"John  
Smith",  
groups  
=>  
$groups,  
id  
=>  
'1234',
```

This is to search all usernames in my target file.It searches everything enclosed with quotes and stores in array arr.

Current Output:

```
"John  
Smith",  
"Abc  
Xyz",  
"...  
...",
```

But i want to achieve this:

```
"John Smith"  
"Abc Xyz"
```

Currently using a for loop to print this and two other arrays.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `'/"*"/'` definitely doesn't do what you think it does. Thats effectively checking if a single quote exists on a line and then printing the line.

Comment: Yes you are right but considering the format of my puppet file, this seems to be working. Any idea on how to match quotes and print anything in between them ?

Comment: Why don't you show us a sample of `output.txt`?

Comment: ok sure @TomFenech updating it in my question

Comment: Needlessly splitting the input into an array is the big blooper here. I arrume simply `awk '/"*"/' output.txt` (or the much simpler equivalent script `grep '"' output.txt`!) prints what you want, but with neither sample input nor the printing code, this is speculation.

Comment: Show us the `for` loop, too; it's pretty clearly buggy.

Comment: I have added to my question to show what is in my output.txt Awk or grep both gives me same output am happy with it but struggling to print them in same line.

Comment: For loop prints three arrays one of them bring arr shown in above example. So i have arr1, arr2 and arr3
for ((i=0; i<=${#arr1[@]}; i++)); 
do
echo ${arr1[i]}
done

Comment: If there are no unpaired quotes in your data, `tr '\n' ' ' <output.txt | grep -o '"[^"]*"'` might be a start.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee that helped me in the right direction. This worked for me -
awk '/^"/ { printf $0 " "; next } sub(/",$/, "\"")' output.txt|tr '""' '\n'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making assumptions about the data from the small sample given, but we can start here and you can let me know if some of those assumptions weren't so good. The main idea is just to not print a new line after reading a line with an opening quote:

```
$  awk '/^"/ { printf "%s ", $0; next } sub(/",$/, "\"")' output.txt
"John Smith"
"Abc Xyz"

$ cat output.txt
user
{
'xx123':
comment
=>
"John
Smith",
groups
=>
$groups,
id
=>
'1234',
=>
"Abc
Xyz",
groups
}
```

Comment: That certainly pointed me in right direction. I have used your command plus tr command and have been successful - This worked for me -->
awk '/^"/ { printf $0 " "; next } sub(/",$/, "\"")' output.txt|tr '""' '\n'

Answer (score 1):

In my first try I missed your point. Here is my correction.

You can try this:

```
printf "%s %s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

Example:

```
$ set|grep BASH_VERSINFO
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="3" [1]="2" [2]="25" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="i686-redhat-linux-gnu")
$ printf "%s %s\n" "${BASH_VERSINFO[@]}"
3 2
25 1
release i686-redhat-linux-gnu
```

I hope this is what your are looking for...

If there is no space in the array elements, then `${BASH_VERSINFO[@]}` or `${BASH_VERSINFO[*]}` can be used, but `"${BASH_VERSINFO[@]}"` is safer.

On the other hand it is better to implement inside [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) as `jas` mentioned. If you do some other manipulation with `arr` then this can be a proper solution.

If the input file is small it can be implemented inside [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).

I think the used pattern `"*"` is not what you are intended to use. This check for zero or more occurrences of `"` followed by `"`. I think you wanted to check for `".*"` or `"[^"]*"` or something like these...

Comment: Hi I am using this echo in a for loop already, sorry will update my question

Answer (score 1):

While I agree the `awk` solution is probably the shortest way to handle the case, the same can be done using the bash built-in comparison, string-indexes and parameter expansion (substring removal). For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

first=""
while read -r last; do 
    [ "${last:0:1}" = '"' ] && first="$last"
    [ "${last:(-2)}" = '",' ] && printf "%s %s\n" "$first" "${last%,}"
done <"$1"
```

Will provide the same output for your given input file, e.g.:

```
$ bash merge2l.sh file.txt
"John Smith"
"Abc Xyz"
```